# How to create a notebook in EMR Studio using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr, aws-emr-studio

I am going through the boto3 documentation here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.create_studio

but I cannot see any sort of create/delete notebook for EMR studio. Only create/delete studio.

How can I create a emr-studio-notebook that preloads a notebook deployed somewhere on S3 via boto3?

Answer (score 1):

Create/delete notebook(Workspace) operations can only be performed using EMR Studio UI and there are no CLI/SDK available for them as of today. You can create Workspace from EMR Studio and upload your existing notebook file via JupyterLab UI.